# Combining 2 regular expression in web.config passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

I am not able to combine below two regular expressions. Password standard requirement:

- Password cannot contain your username or parts of your full name
  exceeding two consecutive characters
- Passwords must be at least 6 characters in length
- Passwords must contain characters from three of the following categories

  - Uppercase characters (English A-Z)
  - Lowercase characters (English a-z)
  - Base 10 digits (0-9)
  - Non-alphabetic characters (e.g., !, @, #, $, %, etc.)

Expression:

```
passwordStrengthRegularExpression="((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})"
```

Passwords cannot contain the word “Test” or “test” or variants of the word

```
passwordStrengthRegularExpression="((?=.*\"^((?!Test|test|TEST).*)$"
```

Both  are working fine individually.

Comment: Dont think your first regex is actually working fine if you want to meet the requirements in bullets above it. Clamps to 20 chars but doesn't say you have to. Requires all four of the categories but requirements says 3 of the 4. Doesn't check the username requirement at all.

Answer (score 2):

Because your second regexp primarily uses a negative lookahead, you can remodel that slightly and stick it right at the beginning of the other expression. First, I'm going to change your second regex to:

```
"(?!.*(?:Test|test|TEST))"
```

In english, the string may not contain any number of (or zero) characters followed by test.

Then, I'm going to stick that right at the beginning of your other expression

```
passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^(?!.*(?:Test|test|TEST))(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20}$"
```

Finally, I'm going to show you how to make only one part of a regex case-insensitive. This may or may not be supported depending on what program this is actually for.

```
passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^(?!.*(?i:test))(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20}$"
```

See the `(?i:...)`? That means that the flags between the `?` and the `:` are applied only to that part of the expression, that is, only that area is case-insensitive.

Comment: Dan's contribution to this has improved it but I dont think the initial expression actually worked as intended. It seems to require all four of the variants (cap, lower, num, symbol) but bullets in OP's question say require 3 of them. Final solution is likely a combination of Dan's and mine...

Comment: Also the whole thing needs wrapping in ^ and $ or it will match it if part of the password meets the requirement, eg `TestUser6@` matches `estUser6@`

Comment: That's fair, since I didn't actually read the requirements. I can't think of a good way to require 3 out of 4. (yours works but I can't consider it to be clean)

Comment: Dan, just interested, what makes you say it isnt clean, because it repeats the requirements in permutations for each combination of the 3 required types? I actually had a bit of an aha! moment when I saw it.

Comment: Because it's inelegant. You're forced to repeat the four character classes three times each, and it's just on the border of being manageable. If you happened to add a fifth class or change the requirements slightly, it would be harder to change and harder to read than a solution in software with several regexes. It's just not necessarily something that regular expressions are well-suited for.

Comment: Yeah I agree, normally I would opt for several regex over one complex one. In this case its used by the asp.net internals so only option is to jam the whole thing in to one web.config setting.

Answer (score 1):

Combining your requirements and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2860380/156388 i've come up with this:

```
(?=^[^\s]{6,}$)(?!.*(?i:test))((?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])|(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[^\w\d\s])(?=.*?[a-z])|(?=.*?[^\w\d\s])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])|(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[^\w\d\s]))^.*
```

Dont think your first regex is actually working fine if you want to meet the requirements in bullets above it. Clamps to 20 chars but doesn't say you have to. Requires all four of the categories but requirements says 3 of the 4. Doesn't check the username requirement at all. So I've gutted out most of the initial regex.

It matches these (as expected):

```
Short5
TeSamplePrd6
TEBREaKST6
WinningUser6@
```

It fails on these (as expected):

```
SamplePassword
TestUser6@
Shrt5
TeSTTest
```

### Remaining problems

For some reason it matches this:

```
TEBREKST6
```

but it only meets two of the four requirements + min length - not sure why?

There is nothing taken into account about the "Password cannot contain your username or parts of your full name exceeding two consecutive characters" requirement and I'm not sure you can even do this through web.config min password requirement as you dont have access to it within the regex.

Comment: Not quite. You made it *require* instead of *prohibit* 'test'. Also, having a maximum length doesn't really mean anything without the `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: Yeah been working on it since but seems like you have already cracked it

Comment: @user2637964 its been updated since you made that comment btw